# "insufficient privileges" error creating a new user

Tags: oracle

I have installed Oracle 11g on my PC. When I try to create a user in SQL*Plus I get an error:

```
SQL>create user scott identified by scott;
                                   *
ERROR at Line 1:
ORA-01031:insufficient privilages
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As what user are you logged in?

Comment: Well, the user you are already connected as doesn't have sufficient privileges to create other users. Which user are you connected as - perhaps show how you log in to SQL\*Plus, hiding the password - and what privileges have they been granted?

Comment: *I have installed Oracle 11g on my PC* Then why didn't you use the Password Management to unlock the user while installation itself? Anyway, now you need to connect as SYSTEM and then do it. Else, as one time activity, do, `SQLPLUS / AS SYSDBA` and execute the statement. Don't abuse SYSDBA privilege later on.